# Can I use dynamic cookie names in PHP 5

Tags: php, session, cookies

For our site visitors must complete a form to get access.  This sets a cookie so that they will not have to fill out the form more than once for the same access.  However if they try to access another part of the site they loss the access they had before. We are not storing any login information in cookies.

These is what we currently use and works:

```
setcookie('oursite_Bids', $_SESSION['bidnumber'], time()+2764800, "/", ".oursite.com", 0);  
setcookie('Bid_Access_Form', $_SESSION['docs'], time()+2764800, "/", ".oursite.com", 0);
```

This is us trying do make the cookie dynamic and neither of these work:

```
setcookie($bidnumber, $_SESSION['docs'], time()+2764800, "/", ".oursite.com", 0);      
setcookie($_SESSION['bidnumber'], $_SESSION['docs'], time()+2764800, "/", ".oursite.com", 0);
```

Is there a way to do this correctly, or am I forced to call the cookie by it's set name, like I currently do?

Comment: Can you show some $bidnumber values and some $_SESSION['docs']?

Answer (score 0):

You are reinventing the wheel for sessions.  Don't do that.

Use regular sessions:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['oursite_Bids'] = 'whatever you want';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Thank you for the response.  However I do not believe that I am "reinventing the wheel for sessions" as we use sessions heavily.  But with a cookie we can allow them to get, and us track, multiple bids.  With them able to return to each of them within a time range set for each.  Each bid has to be managed separately and we believe that cookie will allow us to do this if the cookie name can be the bid number.  However right or wrong, this could be very handy it we can get it to work like we want.

Comment: @DougGammon Why wouldn't you just track each bid in session data?  Far easier than using a cookie directly..

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
$bidnumber = $_SESSION['bidnumber'];  
$cookiename = str_replace(' ', '_', $bidnumber);  
setcookie($cookiename, $_SESSION['docs'], time()+2764800, "/", ".oursite.com", 0);
```

The one I used above did not work because the value of `$bidnumber` contained a space character.

Thanks everyone for your input.